# fluent plugin kafka json escaping

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, fluentd

I am using version [`fluent-plugin-kafka` version 0.12.3](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka/releases/tag/v0.12.3).

I have an application that outputs its logs in JSON format, but my console consumer shows that the logs are escaped.

for instance, the application output the following log line:

```
{
  "msg": "ok"
}
```

when i look at the log using the console consumer, it outputs:

```
{
  "container_id": "7e...",
  "container_name": "/app",
  "source": "stdout",
  "log": "{\"msg\": \"ok\"}"
}
```

how should `fluent-plugin-kafka` should be configured so the application log will be nested as a json without escaping it?

desired output:

```
{
  "container_id": "7e...",
  "container_name": "/app",
  "source": "stdout",
  "log": {
    "msg": "ok"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [record transformer filter](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer) i was able to mutate the incoming data.